# Automatically Assign Employee Number In Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 1 DataGridView with 3 columns, 1 button named as **AssignID**, 1 Database with **EmployeeList** Table.

Columns of Datagridview

1. Column 1 = EmployeeID
2. Column 2 = EmployeeName
3. Column 3 = Department

I'm pasting the data of **EmployeeName** and **Department** from excel into DataGridView leaving column 1 as blank. My problem is how to automatically assign the **EmployeeID** per Employee in the DataGridView when I press the button **AssignID**. The last **IDNumber** in the database is 10000.

Appreciate your help. Im still learning vb.net. Thanks in Advance.

Im using below code:

```
Private Sub AssignID_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AssignID.Click
    Dim Dbcon As New OleDbConnection(connStr)

    Dbcon.Open()

    Dim query As String
    Dim dbup As New OleDbCommand
    Try

        query = "SELECT Max (EmployeeID) from EmployeeList"
        dbup = New OleDbCommand(query, Dbcon)

        Dim EmpID As Integer

        EmpID = dbup.ExecuteScalar

        Dim i2 As Integer
        i2 = Me.NewEmployeesDataGridview.CurrentRow.Index

        NewEmployeesDataGridview.Item(0, i2).Value() = EmpID

        For x As Integer = 0 To NewEmployeesDataGridview.Rows.Count - 2
            NewEmployeesDataGridview.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = NewEmployeesDataGridview.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value + 1

        Next

        NewEmployeesDataGridview.AllowUserToAddRows = False

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your problem. Are you trying to get how to grab the right ID with the right person in your datagridview cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last assigned ID in the table is 10,000, then the next ID is 10,000 + 1, that is 10,001. Therefore:

```
    EmpID = dbup.ExecuteScalar + 1

    '.Note #1: The code that is commented is not necessary
    'Dim i2 As Integer
    'i2 = Me.NewEmployeesDataGridview.CurrentRow.Index
    '
    'NewEmployeesDataGridview.Item(0, i2).Value() = EmpID
    '.Note #1.

    'To Rows.Count - 1 throw the correct result:
    NewEmployeesDataGridview.AllowUserToAddRows = False

    'For each row in the datagridview, we increase by one each ID from the last ID
    For x As Integer = 0 To NewEmployeesDataGridview.Rows.Count - 1
        NewEmployeesDataGridview.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = EmpID + x
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used that method before, but I would probably use a datadapter. It's easier to think in datarows and tables.

For example:

```
 Dim connection As SqlConnection = New sqlconnection()
  connection.ConnectionString = "<whatever your connection string is>"
  connection.Open()
  Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter _
  (SELECT Max (EmployeeID) from EmployeeList)   
  Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

  'fill adapter
  adp.Fill(ds)  
  Dim DT as datatable = ds.Tables(0)
```

So, in DT you will have a datatable, of assuming only with 1 row with the employee you requested as its contents. Then you can grab the value like so:

```
Dim empID as integer = DT.rows(0).item("<name of SQL column with employee ID>")
```

Then you loop through each row in the datagridview, and look for the right row that has the employee you want to change.

```
NewEmployeesDataGridview.Rows(<integer of row>).Cells(<integer of column with IDs>).Value = empID
```

That's just one way to do it. The you can just find the row with that employee and assign that to the proper cell in a for loop. Or use LINQ, if you're up to it, and distinct() to find it that way more quickly.

Comment: Its working now. Thank you very much Aprendiendo.NET!